# Button is not working inside custom dialog which is appeared after long press of a button

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick, customdialog

I have opened a custom dialog inside longPress of a button,
Inside that custom dialog i have two buttons and one edit text. I want to change the name of the button which i have longpressed with the name which i get from the edit text inside the custom dialog, the buttons are not working.

```
public void initializeLPButtons(Button[] btns, int[] rArrays) {

    for(i=0; i<btns.length; i++) {

        btns[i] = (Button) findViewById(rArrays[i]);
        btns[i].setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                renameBtn();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void renameBtn() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setView(R.layout.dialog_renamebtn);
    dialog.setTitle("Rename Button...");
    dialog.setMessage("Rename The Button To:");

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_renamebtn, null);

    renameEt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.renameEt);
    renameBtn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.renameBtn);
    cnclRenameBtn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cnlRenameBtn);

    cnclRenameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    renameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            renameBtnTxt();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

public void renameBtnTxt() {

    if (renameEt.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        btns[i].setText(renameEt.getText().toString());
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please choose a name.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I dont think my code has problems. Please if it is something with java help me find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your dialog like this:

```
private void CreateGetPhoneNumDialog() {
        Dialog PhoneNumberDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        PhoneNumberDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        PhoneNumberDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mobile_number_pop_message);
        PhoneNumberDialog.setCancelable(false);
}
```

Get edittext and button's reference after creating the dialog

```
etDialogPhoneNum = (EditText) PhoneNumberDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_DialogCustomerPhone);
btnGetPhoneNum = (Button) PhoneNumberDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_DialogGetPhoneNum);
```

Then set on click listener on dialog's button

```
btnGetPhoneNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Do your work here
       }
});
```

mobile_number_pop_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_DialogCustomerPhone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:maxLength="9"
        android:hint="512345678"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/str_UpdatePhoneNumber"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btn_DialogGetPhoneNum" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:**

And show the dialog like this:

```
PhoneNumberDialog.show();
```

Comment: this works, but it needs dialog.show too.
I dont know why someone have scored minus my question.

Comment: yes, i forgot to add that, thanks for pointing out. I edited my answer.